# Haskell: Concatenating Lists without using (++)

Tags: list, haskell, merge, concatenation, addition

I am trying to write a function that will combine 2 lists without using "divide and conquer". Therefore I cannot use `(++)`.

`Prelude> let combineList (x:xs) (y:ys) = if null (y:ys)==True then x:xs else combineList (x:xs++[y]) (ys)`

This is what I have right now, and I get `"Non-exhaustive patterns in function combineList"`. I realize that the problem comes from `if null (y:ys)==True`, because this function works -

`Prelude> let combineList (x:xs) (y:ys) = if ys==[] then x:xs++[y] else combineList (x:xs++[y]) (ys)`

but I'd like to get rid of the `++[y]` in the output if possible.

Correction to the code is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Your `combineList` should basically do what `++` does, but it shouldn't *use* `++` to achieve this?

Comment: That is correct, I shouldn't use ++ to achieve this.

Comment: You can just [look at the source of `(++)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B).

Comment: Sorry Daniel, it's only my second class in computer science, I'm not sure if i know what the source means as I've only learned how to do things on one line. Correction to my code would be appreciated.

Comment: also, `(++) = flip (foldr (:))` extensionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(x:xs)` does not match any list. Rather, it matches a list with a head element `x` and a tail `xs`. (You could sort of think of it as matching a *cons* cell, I guess.) `null (x:xs)` also can't ever be false, because any `(x:xs)` is not null, basically by definition.

`"Non-exhaustive patterns in function"` means the input could not be matched to a pattern for the function. In this case, neither argument can be null, so if either is null, you will have a match failure.

Since you're apparently doing it with `if`s, you'll want to match *any* list, so the function will look like

```
combineList xs ys = if null xs then ys else head xs : combineList (tail xs) ys
```

A more usual way to do this in haskell, however, would be to pattern-match against the `nil` pattern separately:

```
cl [] ys = ys
cl (x:xs) ys = x : cl xs ys
```

(this is equivalent to the definition of `(++)`, but in prefix form:)

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
 -- or         = x : (++) xs ys
```

It also follows the *fold* pattern: we can accumulate consing over the first list, with the second list used as the initial tail:

```
cl' xs ys = foldr (:) ys xs
```

This also allows us to write the function pointlessly (i.e. in [pointfree](/questions/tagged/pointfree) style):

```
cl'' = flip (foldr (:))
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning `` "Non-exhaustive patterns in function `combineList`" `` means that your function doesn't  pattern match every constructor of the *data type*. `List` type contains two constructors, `(:)` and `[]`; when you use pattern matching the compiler assumes that you want to match every constructor of the data type.

Here is one possible solution:

```
combineList (x:xs) ys = if null xs then x : ys else x : combineList xs ys
```

In Haskell a better way to write this is using pattern matching. Note that this is also  the actual definition of `(++)`:

```
combineList []     ys = ys 
combineList (x:xs) ys = x : combineList xs ys
```